# Mock returns incorrect value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing an API using Mockito. The lines that I am trying to mock looks like this:

```
[Controller.java]
...
List<File> meta = service1.getListOfFiles();
List<String> files = service2.getFilenames(meta);
...
for (String s : strFromRequest) {
   if (!files.contains(s)) { /*Throw exception 404*/ }
}

--------

[Service2.java]
public List<String> getFilenames(List<File> meta) {
    return meta.stream().map(f -> f.getFileName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In my test code, I want to manipulate "files" so I can test it with various values (ex. empty, with data, etc) and I have tried something like below, also tweaked to doReturn/when.

```
List<File> meta = /*set fake data*/
List<String> filesList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class); /*set fake data*/
when(service1.getListOfFiles()).thenReturn(meta);
when(service2.getFilenames(meta)).thenReturn(filesList);
```

Although "filesList" is already set, it always returns empty thus instead of success, exception is always thrown.

I am still new to Mockito and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where/how are you declaring your mocks? In particular `service1` and `service2`.

Comment: What is `fileMetaList`?

Comment: `List<String> filesList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class); /*set fake data*/`.
This might be problematic. Consider using `spy` here

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, mocking the `ArrayList` class is likely to cause problems. Since you're looking to create a `List` of `String`s, something like `List.of(fakeDataString1, fakeDataString2, fakeDataString3)` does a better, safer job of setting that fake data.

The problem with mocking `ArrayList` is that you end up needing to mock many and/or exact methods. In this particular case, your code only uses the `contains` method...so technically speaking, that would be the only method that you'd need to explicitly mock. However, it's much simpler and safer to create a list than to mock even just the `contains` method.